# Fun with repeated fmap

Tags: haskell, functor

I was playing around with functors, and I noticed something interesting:

Trivially, `id` can be instantiated at the type `(a -> b) -> a -> b`.

With the list functor we have `fmap :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`, which is the same as `map`.

In the case of the `((->) r)` functor (from `Control.Monad.Instances`), `fmap` is function composition, so we can instantiate `fmap fmap fmap :: (a -> b) -> [[a]] -> [[b]]`, which is equivalent to `(map . map)`.

Interestingly, `fmap` eight times gives us `(map . map . map)`!

So we have

```
0: id = id
1: fmap = map
3: fmap fmap fmap = (map . map)
8: fmap fmap fmap fmap fmap fmap fmap fmap = (map . map . map)
```

Does this pattern continue? Why/why not? Is there a formula for how many `fmap`s I need to map a function over an *n*-times nested list?

I tried writing a test script to search for a solution to the *n = 4* case, but GHC starts eating too much memory at around 40 `fmap`s.

Comment: It degenerates pretty quickly into a cycle or something like it, but I've forgotten the exact formula. (Incidentally, [lambdabot](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Lambdabot) actually defines `(.)` as `fmap`.)

Comment: @ehird: I think you're right. It seems like `fmap` _n = 4k_ times (for n at least 8) gives `(map . map . map)`. I'm still curious about why this happens, though. Especially because the instances change. At _n = 8_ it's `(.) (.) (.) (.) (.)  map map map`, while for _n = 12_ it's `(.) (.) (.) (.) (.) (.) (.) (.) map (.) map map`.

Answer (score 36):

I can't explain why, but here's the proof of the cycle:

Assume `k >= 2` and `fmap^(4k) :: (a -> b) -> F1 F2 F3 a -> F1 F2 F3 b`, where `Fx` stands for an unknown/arbitrary `Functor`. `fmap^n` stands for `fmap` applied to `n-1` `fmap`s, not `n`-fold iteration. The induction's start can be verified by hand or querying ghci.

```
fmap^(4k+1) = fmap^(4k) fmap
fmap :: (x -> y) -> F4 x -> F4 y
```

unification with a -> b yields `a = x -> y`, `b = F4 x -> F4 y`, so

```
fmap^(4k+1) :: F1 F2 F3 (x -> y) -> F1 F2 F3 (F4 x -> F4 y)
```

Now, for `fmap^(4k+2)` we must unify `F1 F2 F3 (x -> y)` with `(a -> b) -> F5 a -> F5 b`.
Thus `F1 = (->) (a -> b)` and `F2 F3 (x -> y)` must be unified with `F5 a -> F5 b`.
Hence `F2 = (->) (F5 a)` and `F3 (x -> y) = F5 b`, i.e. `F5 = F3` and `b = x -> y`. The result is

```
fmap^(4k+2) :: F1 F2 F3 (F4 x -> F4 y)
             = (a -> (x -> y)) -> F3 a -> F3 (F4 x -> F4 y)
```

For `fmap^(4k+3)`, we must unify `a -> (x -> y)` with `(m -> n) -> F6 m -> F6 n)`, giving `a = m -> n`,
`x = F6 m` and `y = F6 n`, so

```
fmap^(4k+3) :: F3 a -> F3 (F4 x -> F4 y)
             = F3 (m -> n) -> F3 (F4 F6 m -> F4 F6 n)
```

Finally, we must unify `F3 (m -> n)` with `(a -> b) -> F7 a -> F7 b`, so `F3 = (->) (a -> b)`, `m = F7 a` and `n = F7 b`, therefore

```
fmap^(4k+4) :: F3 (F4 F6 m -> F4 F6 n)
             = (a -> b) -> (F4 F6 F7 a -> F4 F6 F7 b)
```

and the cycle is complete. Of course the result follows from querying ghci, but maybe the derivation sheds some light on how it works.

Answer (score 2):

I'll give a slightly simpler answer: `map` is a specialization of `fmap` and `(.)` is *also* a specialization of `fmap`. So, by substitution, you get the identity you discovered!

If you're interested in going further, Bartosz Milewski has a nice [writeup](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2015/09/01/the-yoneda-lemma/) that uses the Yoneda Lemma to make explicit why function composition is a monad.